# unable to edit nginx.conf file from K8 cluster

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress, nginx-config

I want to edit my `Nginx.conf` file present inside Nginx controller pod in AKS, but the edit command is not working using the exec command, is there any way else I could edit my `nginx.conf`.

the command which I tried:

```
kubectl exec -it nginx-nginx-ingress-controller -n nginx --  cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by CrowDev, it's not good practice to update the config of Nginx controller like that.

Nginx controller is the backend of the **ingress** you can use the **config map** to update the configuration of the Nginx controller and redeploy the pod of the controller.

Some of the **Nginx controller** config could be also overwritten using the ingress config and annotation inside it.

You can read more about annotation here : https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/

**Update** :

You can separate out different ingress by their **name**. if you want to manage different configs or headers you need to separate out ingress for managing different configs.

Example :

**ingress : 1**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-one
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /one
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: one
            port:
              number: 80
```

**ingress : 2**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-two
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /two
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: two
            port:
              number: 80
```

now `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"` will get apply to only one ingress or service.

Comment: in ingress file multiple services are mapped and the nginx.conf is taking parameters for each services commonly from these ingress file configurations. so if i want to make some changes specifically for one service say one gateway out of 10 gateways. is there anyway i could do it ? while adding in ingress.yaml it is commonly reflecting for all

Comment: could you please share the ingres.yaml demo how you are managing it? ideally, each ingress with name is different configuration and you can pass or change annotation and parameters diff. for each one of them.

Comment: apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cafe-ingress-with-annotations
  annotations:
    nginx.org/proxy-connect-timeout: "30s"
    nginx.org/proxy-read-timeout: "20s"
    nginx.org/client-max-body-size: "4m"
    nginx.org/server-snippets: |
      location / {
        return 302 /coffee;
      }      
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cafe.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /tea
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: tea-svc
            port:
              number: 80

Comment: consider this to be an example if I want to change nginx.org/proxy-read-timeout: "20s"  to " 100s" only for the service name tea-svc and not any other services present inside that ingress file. how will I be able to acheive that? specifying like how which it is alredy present, this gets applicable to all services.

Comment: so proxy read timeout is getting updated for all ingresses right ? but you want to just update for one ?

Comment: proxy-next-upstream: "error timeout http_502 http_404 non_idempotent" , i want to add this specifically to one service present inside our ingress, proxy timeout was an example

Comment: try this annotaion in ingres `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout`

Comment: not sure why you are using nginx.org try once with above shared suggestion and please check once.

Comment: i have tried this, but it is coming commonly for all services, say like i am having tea coffee juice..lke that 10 services. when this is given it is getting applied for all 10. but when i want to make this only for one service like tea, that is not possible

Comment: oh, that's weird give me a few min let me check on that and verify once.

Comment: and how do you cross check it? by checking configfile inside nginx pod right ?

Comment: I am using the same: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout. I took other from an example code only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241921/discussion-between-harsh-manvar-and-rughma-sussan-renji).

Comment: yeah crosschecking by checking the nginx.conf file from pod

Answer (score 1):

yh, seems this is also working. tried an alternative way:

`Edit/add` the properties to change in `ingress.yaml` and redeploy it. the changes will then reflect in `nginx.conf`

Comment: if i need to make these changes to be reflected specifically for one service among all other present in ingress, is there any way I could do that ?

Comment: what changes you are doing could you please share that without that no one will be able to answer.

Comment: someone config like tls version and other things on controller level if you will try to update it, that could be applied to other ingresses. but it depends on changes what you are trying for example, if you want to tweak the header to any specfic ingress you can apply to only one also.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is a bad idea to exec into a pod to do changes. It violates the principle of infrastructure as code. You should extract the nginx.conf file to a ConfigMap and then mount it into the pod.

An example can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/petitviolet/d36f33d145d0bbf4b54eb187b79d0244).

You can then edit the ConfigMap when needing to update the nginx config. Remember to redeploy the Pod to make the config apply.

Answer (score 0):

I read from the official you are able to configure or modify the nginx.conf through annotation or configmap.

what you need is to modify your ingress file. first, check your ingress by

```
kubectl get ingress -A
```

you will see your ingress there, how did you create the ingress? of course, you execute the ingress file which is the YAML file. now you need to edit the file and add some annotation [annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations) or [confgimap](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap)